# Verilog behavioral program for a state machine that samples a continuous stream of synchronized data on an input line X

Tags: verilog

[image]

QUESTION:

Write a Verilog behavioral program for a state machine that samples a continuous stream of synchronized data on an input line X. The state machine is to an output Z any  time  the  sequence  `….0110…`  occurs.  Consider  that  the  sequence  may  be 
overlapping. For example,

`X = 0011001101100110`
`Z = 0000100010010001`

```
module find_data(in,out);
  parameter check=4'b0110;
  input [15:0]in;
  output [15:0]out;
  reg [15:0]x;
  reg [15:0]z;
  reg [3:0]maxfourchar_x,an;

  always begin
    x=in;
    z=out;
    maxfourchar_x=x[15:12];
    repeat(12) begin
      x=x<<1;
      z=z<<1;
      an= maxfourchar_x - check;
      if (an==0)
        z=z+1;
      else
        z=0;
    end
  end
endmodule

module test_find_data();
  reg [15:0]in;
  wire [15:0]out;

  initial $display("z=%b%b%b%b%b%b%b%b%b%b%b%b%b%b%b%b",out[15],out[14],out[13],out[12],ou‌​t[11],out[10],out[9],out[8],out[7],out[6],out[5],out[4],out[3],out[2],out[1],out[‌​0]);
  initial in=16'b0011001101100110;
  find_data d1(in,out);
endmodule
```

Comment: Please don't (only) post screenshots of code, it can't be edited/looked at easily. Also, please tell us what you have tried?

Comment: module find_data(in,out);
   parameter check=4'b0110;
   input [15:0]in;
   output [15:0]out;
   reg [15:0]x;
   reg [15:0]z;
   reg [3:0]maxfourchar_x,an;
   always
      begin
        x=in;
        z=out;   
         maxfourchar_x=x[15:12];
           repeat(12)
            begin 
                  x=x<<1;
                  z=z<<1;
                  an= maxfourchar_x - check;
                  if (an==0)
                   z=z+1;
                  else z=0; 
            end       
      end

endmodule

Comment: module test_find_data();
    reg [15:0]in;
    wire [15:0]out;
    
    initial
          $display("z=%b%b%b%b%b%b%b%b%b%b%b%b%b%b%b%b",out[15],out[14],out[13],out[12],out[11],out[10],out[9],out[8],out[7],out[6],out[5],out[4],out[3],out[2],out[1],out[0]);
      initial
        in=16'b 0011001101100110;     
  find_data d1(in,out);  
endmodule

Comment: result z=zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz and I don't know where wrong

Comment: Your assignment ask to write a "state machine" which uses a clock. `0011001101100110` is a data stream, not parallel input.

Answer (score 1):

You have used 'initial' block in your test_find_data() module. Statements under 'initial' blocks run **only once, at time = 0**.

You are printing the value of 'z' at 't = 0'

Please see [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programmable_Logic/Verilog_Always_and_Initial) or [here](http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/vbehave1.html).

Comment: OH! Thank you. So.. should I use clock?

Comment: Please go through this for more details. [link]https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/sp07/cse141L/lab1/test_primer.pdf